# Phoenix Elixir main module cannot load?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Just learning Elixir and phoenix FW today and I ran into this problem and google isn't helping much: **I can't use everything, the controller, routes, etc, because the main module isn't loading**

[image]

See the error on the bottom of the IDE: Module Blog.Web isn't loaded and could not be found.

[image]

This is the module `Blog.Web` on `web.ex`.

Now I can't access everything:

[image]

Can someone please explain what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: post your complete routes file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says undefinedFunctionError at GET/posts.

Can you post your full controller implementation and your router.ex?

P/s: I can't comment so i will edit this post.

Comment: routes file has this: resources "/posts", PostController

Comment: ahhh i see what's wrong, i didn't put it inside scope, thanks

Comment: you are welcome.And you might want to check Elixir on Slack to get a quick response.People are so enthusiastic and happy to help.https://elixir-slackin.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is actually a bug in the sublime text plugin, https://github.com/vishnevskiy/ElixirSublime/issues/21

Comment: any workaround? like changing the path to read the correct folder or something?